# inject html using js via linked file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototypejs

I'm trying to come up with a way to inject a large amount of html into a document through a linked script but I can't find a good way to do it.

Something like this would go into the head of the document I'm 'injecting' into:

```
<script src="http://example.com/html-inject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then the contents of this guy would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').insert({after: '<div id="test_div"><h1>This is a test.</h1></div>'});
    $('header').insert({after: '<div id="test_div"><h1>This is another test.</h1></div>'});
})
```

(The above would require prototype.js but I would prefer having to link only to a single file...)

The reason I'm trying to do this: I'm trying to come up with a good way to modify a blog theme without tampering with the html that's intricately riddled with variables and blocks

Comment: Fix your blog theme.  That will likely be far easier, and then you won't have an odd FOUC on load while you re-write the page.

Comment: `a good way to modify a blog theme`, have you looked at using jQueryUI, then you could incorporate something like a themeswitcher

Comment: @Brad I could do that, but I'm trying to make a tool here — I want to make this something that could be easily used by anyone trying to modify their theme that might not understand how the site specific variables and blocks work or just want to add a few things here and there

Comment: also, have you looked at jQuery's [.load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)? it doesn't require proto, I **STRONGLY** recommend again using proto with jQuery. Whatever you are doing with proto you can do with jQuery. jQuery also has .before and .after func for various purpose. please read over their api more before u rely on a second lib.

Comment: @SpYk3HH Okay so I did a quick test and made http://ra.gs/custom-html.js and I made a quick html page to inject: http://ra.gs/test-inject.html. I linked the custom-html.js in a document but nothing is showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery (which is fairly standard to include these days), you can do:

```
$('#div').append('<h1>SomeHtml</h1>');
```

But, like others have said, your probably better off learning your blog theme and doing it correctly.